# Django query filter exclude repeated items

Tags: python, django

I want to filter message like this

```
messages = Message.objects.filter(who_id=logged_user) | Q(whose_id=logged_user)
```

my result =

```
who : 1 , whose : 2
who : 2 , whose : 1
who : 1 , whose : 2
who : 2 , whose : 1
who : 1 , whose : 3
```

but I want this result

```
who : 1 , whose : 2
who : 1 , whose : 3
```

my model

```
class Message(models.Model):
    uuid = UUIDField(auto=True)
    who = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,related_name="who_%(class)s_objects")
    whose = models.ForeignKey(User,blank=True,related_name="whose_%(class)s_objects")
    message = models.TextField()
    time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

How to exclude all other results?

Comment: Post your model class definition here.

Comment: @fish_ball question updated with model

Comment: Add distinct() after the filter.

Comment: And what do you mean by **"other results"**? Which cases were "other"?

Answer (score 0):

Your query

messages = Message.objects.filter(who_id=logged_user) | Q(whose_id=logged_user)

returns all messages that:

- have who_id = logged_user OR
- have whose_id = logged_user.

From your question it appears that you only want the messages that

- have who_id = logged_user

I.e

messages = Message.objects.filter(who_id=logged_user)

should work.

If that's not what you're after, please specify the logic of your query.